# python to MATLAB code, lists of numbers and summing

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm completely new to python and Numpy, and I'm trying to rewrite some python code in MATLAB. In the process I found this line which I don't understand  `a=np.array(eval(self.param[7]))[0:6].sum()`; param is an structure containing 8 arrays something like this :

```
param[0]=100;  
param[1]=1;  
param[2]=1.5;                     
param[3]=(1,2,3,4);  
param[4]=(1,1,1,1);  
param[5]=10;  
param[6]=(1,0.,1,1,1,0.,0.,0.);  
param[7]=(2,0.,2,3,6,0.,0.,0.);
```

can someone tell me what does [0:6] and then.sum() do? 
My thought is a is a sum of all the 7 first element in the param[7], but it does not fit to the whole process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[0:6]` will take the first 6 elements in `param[7]` producing the array

```
[2,0.,2,3,6,0.]
```

Then the `.sum()` method will sum the elements in that array.

Just a quick note on [array slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) in python, the expression `x[i:j:k]` will take every k<sup>th</sup> element from the array `x` starting at the i<sup>th</sup> element, upto but **not** including the j<sup>th</sup> element.

If you miss any of them out then python will you assume that you mean the beginning of the array, the end of the array and 1 respectively. So the slice in your code could be slightly more succinctly written as `[:6]`